# Ubuntu 20, touchpad flakey

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, synaptics, elantech

I'm experiencing a lot of trouble with Ubuntu (various flavours) and my laptop Razer Blade 15.

Occasionally the touchpad device stops working, except for accepting tap clicks, it does not scroll, nor moves the cursor or accept right clicks.

I've tried both `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` but neither seem to solve the issue.

The only pointer I have is that when logging events for the touchapad, there is a stream of `EV_MSC` events being spit out when the device is not working correctly, along these lines:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x18 vendor 0x4f3 product 0x30a6 version 0x100
Input device name: "ELAN0406:00 04F3:30A6 Touchpad"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER)
    Event code 328 (BTN_TOOL_QUINTTAP)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP)
    Event code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP)
    Event code 335 (BTN_TOOL_QUADTAP)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value     64
      Min        0
      Max     3995
      Resolution      32
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value   2453
      Min        0
      Max     2453
      Resolution      32
    Event code 47 (ABS_MT_SLOT)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        4
    Event code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     3995
      Resolution      32
    Event code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     2453
      Resolution      32
    Event code 55 (ABS_MT_TOOL_TYPE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        2
    Event code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    65535
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP)
Properties:
  Property type 0 (INPUT_PROP_POINTER)
  Property type 2 (INPUT_PROP_BUTTONPAD)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1600640353.153157, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 1345302500
Event: time 1600640353.153157, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.420487, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823347500
Event: time 1600639839.420487, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.426674, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823354500
Event: time 1600639839.426674, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.433647, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823361500
Event: time 1600639839.433647, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.440182, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823368500
Event: time 1600639839.440182, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.447557, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823375500
Event: time 1600639839.447557, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.454994, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823382500
Event: time 1600639839.454994, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.461102, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823389500
Event: time 1600639839.461102, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.468130, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823396500
Event: time 1600639839.468130, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.474751, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823403500
Event: time 1600639839.474751, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.482152, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823410500
Event: time 1600639839.482152, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.489178, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823417500
Event: time 1600639839.489178, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.495455, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823424500
Event: time 1600639839.495455, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.502352, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823431500
Event: time 1600639839.502352, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.509013, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823438500
Event: time 1600639839.509013, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.516597, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823445500
Event: time 1600639839.516597, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.523406, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823452500
Event: time 1600639839.523406, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.530056, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823459500
Event: time 1600639839.530056, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1600639839.536943, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 823466500
Event: time 1600639839.536943, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

For completeness here is my `xinput` output

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M570                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade Consumer Control        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0406:00 04F3:30A6 Mouse               id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0406:00 04F3:30A6 Touchpad            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera: USB Camera                    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade Keyboard                id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade System Control          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade Consumer Control        id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and here are the touchpad props `xinput list-props 18`

```
Device 'ELAN0406:00 04F3:30A6 Touchpad':
        Device Enabled (171):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (173): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Tapping Enabled (327): 0
        libinput Tapping Enabled Default (328): 0
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (329):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (330):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (331):       0
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (332):       0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (333):  1, 0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (334):  1, 0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (307):       1
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (308):       0
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (335):    0
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (336):    1
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (309):        1, 1, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (310):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (311):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Click Methods Available (337): 1, 1
        libinput Click Method Enabled (338):    0, 1
        libinput Click Method Enabled Default (339):    1, 0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (314):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (315):        0
        libinput Accel Speed (318):     0.400000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (319):     0.000000
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (323):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (324):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (292):     1, 1
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (293):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (294):        0, 0
        Device Node (295):      "/dev/input/event8"
        Device Product ID (296):        1267, 12454
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (325):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (326):       1
```

I imagine more information might be needed but I am somewhat at a loss of what to do next.  I've followed [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection) to no avail. Would highly appreciate some advice.

Comment: Perhaps you could try booting from some other live OS to rule out hardware problems.

Comment: Hi, yes that's been done, as the laptop is a dual boot windows / ubuntu :)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495727/unexpected-touchpad-events-in-evtest-is-this-a-driver-or-kernel-or-firmware-o
Driver issue?
Perhaps updating the kernel, libinput10 and libinput-bin, if possible, helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my mouse not registering clicks randomly.

I did not get to the root cause of the issue. But I got around it by having a keybind to reload the mouse drivers.

```bsh
#Disable driver modules
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
#Re-enable driver modules
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to help unfortunately